# yam.request is undefined with platform_js_sdk.js file

Tags: yammer

I have 2 controls on SharePoint page one is yammer embed feed and 1 content editor webpart with REST API call.

When I refresh page multiple times with some duration then it is throwing error as "yam.request is undefined". Please note I am using platform_js_sdk.js for REST API.

@Yammer team: can you please try and check issue with platform_js_sdk.js file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, having two yammer feeds on the same page doesn't work well, whether it be with embed or the rest api.  One workaround is to use a page viewer web part which hosts the individual pieces of functionality.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks. just would like to know is there any Yammer documentation which says about recommended controls to use on same page?

Comment: Nope... Documentation on these nuances is sometimes lacking